# Python Julian date to Gregorian date conversion error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, django-views

i get the error message:an integer is required

when i am try to convert from Julian date to  Gregorian date

in my view.py, after i have query the db i want to convert the date_entered from Julian date to Gregorian date but i got the above error.

```
# inside view.py

convert_date=(datetime.date.fromordinal(rate.columns.date_entered))
```

Comment: in the template i did something like <td>{{test}}</td>

Comment: i think test=datetime.date.fromordinal(int(a.date_entered)) has to be filter to accommodate the range of selected dates (convert,convert1). But i have to idea how this is going to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your returned `date_entered` has not been converted to an integer and `datetime.date.fromordinal()` requires an integer. Assuming a valid string value, all you need is to *'cast'* it to an integer:

```
convert_date = datetime.date.fromordinal(int(rate.columns.date_entered))
```

Comment: Thanks. i applied convert_date = datetime.date.fromordinal(int(rate.columns.date_entered))   But i get an error int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'. So i change the code to convert_date = datetime.date.fromordinal(int(str(rate.columns.date_entered))). but i get the error message:   

invalid literal for int() with base 10: tablename

Comment: @sum - Where do you obtain `rate.columns.date_entered` from?

Comment: from a database table

Comment: @sum - The issue is that you're having an SQLAlchemy `Column`, not the actual value - that's why I asked where are you getting it from. You need to extract the value from it for your given row.

Comment: Thanks, i was actually trying to convert all the value in the column. Is there are a way to do that in the django template  in a for loop?

Comment: from the template  {%for a in results %} <td>{{a.date_entered}}</td>{%endfor%} when it display the date values are in julian is there are way to convert the value to Gregorian date  form the template

Comment: i did something like this                                                                                
            stmt=stmt.where(and_(rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num==fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,fund.columns.account_code==selected_acc,rate.columns.date_entered.between(convert,convert1)))

            result_proxy=connection.execute(stmt)
            for a in result_proxy:
                test=datetime.date.fromordinal(int(a.date_entered))  after passing the parameter to the template i select the rage of date for example from date to end date. it only display start date not end date

Comment: @sum - Can you update your question (or make a new one) actually explaining the issue at hand? Post your relevant code (including the code you use to obtain the data from your database) and template and explain what you want it do to versus what it does. It's quite difficult to discern the actual issue from the comments.